# How to properly resize a scrollview in android

Tags: android, scrollview

I have been trying to resize a scrollview, but with no success. I tried setting `android:fillViewport="true"` it didn't work out. I tried again to set it using the java code:

```
 scroller = (ScrollView) this.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
 scroller.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 300));
```

The application just crashed. I want to keep the size of scrollview constant. To be more precise, when the text is too large, scrollview should not occupy all screen, but just a part of it.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mytext"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/text"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:text="Ok" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**EDIT**

```
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bledi.ui/com.bledi.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360):    at com.bledi.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-19 15:36:14.570: E/AndroidRuntime(11360):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First point, shown in the crash log, means object not instantiated at some point.

I think if you want a text scroll, but do not stay within predefined space, you can do something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Your big text here!"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Ok" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the size of `scrollview` constant you should define it size in layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="300dip" >
........
...........
</ScrollView>
```

As you defined:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

The width takes the width of the screen and the height is adjusted to the content height

Comment: That would be great just like your wrote, but I am afraid we are not allowed to use integer values, as an error shows up `Integer types not allowed (at 'layout_height' with value '300')`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the findViewById cannot find your ScrollView.

Did you put setContentView in onCreate?

Comment: yeap I did put `setContentView` in `onCreate`